# Integration of a SharePoint Framwork in a Visual webpart SharePoint On Premise

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, sharepoint-framework

After creation of a solution with SharePoint Framework, how can we integrate JS generated files in a Visual Webpart?

Is there is a possibility to do that?

Comment: could you explain in a bit more detail what you mean by Javascript generated files? do you mean how do you use JS files in a visual webpart and where do you store JS files for reference? also what version of sharepoint you using? sorry for the questions... just makes it easier to answer

Comment: hello Ali, 
i mean js files generated in dist folder after using Gulp serve command.
i would like to create a visual webpart in a farm solution ( SP2013 on permise) call the js file in the webpart :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that SharePoint 2013 will ever support SPFx.  I don't think it's on the near term roadmap for SP 2016 either.